# Including Excel Object Names in VBA Validate Lists

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010, vba

In an answer to another question, I saw a suggested example of a Validate List entry as:

```
 With rng.Validation
     .Delete 'delete previous validation
     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Formula1:="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & range1.Address
 End With
```

This works fine but, if possible, rather than include a worksheet's name in Formula1, I'd rather include the Excel Object name (e.g. Sheet1, Sheet2, etc). In this way if someone choses to rename the worksheet then the macro would still work unedited.

Is this possible and, if so, what's the best way to include it in the Formula1, please?

Comment: Named ranges are global to the workbook by default and don't need the sheet name

Comment: The macro will still work if someone renames a worksheet. It's just that the validation won't work after the name change, since the Formula1 result from the initial run will be incorrect afterwards.
Rerunning the macro would instantly fix that though.
`Formula1` takes a "regular" excel formula in string format, so using the object's name there is not possible.

Comment: Edit: My bad - Actually Excel will update the formula automatically when a user changes the sheet name. The code you posted just takes the name from a worksheet variable. There's no need to reference anything else, at all. In other words "In this way if someone choses to rename the worksheet then the macro would still work unedited." - This doesn't apply.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm new to this. I've now created a small test and when, in my version, I changed the worksheets name, saved and closed the workbook, and reopened it, the macro failed.

Comment: I suspect that I set the WS.name up incorrectly - I used "Dim WS As Worksheet" and then "Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Configuration")". When I changed the Worksheet's name from "Configuration" to "Eric" (I know, I know) I got "Run-time error '9':"    "Subscript out of range"

Answer (score 2):

Simply use, and I recommend it in *all cases*, the range's address including the sheet's name *implicitly*

```
Formula1:="=" & range1.Address(External:=True)
```

`External:=True` will include the parent sheet in the reference, whatever it is at the moment and however it changes later.

p.s. the sheet's name will be present in the formula but if the user changes a sheet name Excel will automatically update all formulas that reference it, except if inside an `INDIRECT` function. So the issue you worry about isn't an actual issue.

Consider this as only the recommended way to set an *external* reference.

Comment: This still sets the formula1 as is at macro execution time - The issue happens when a user changes the sheet name according to OP. However - I just tested that and it's a non-issue in the first place, since Excel actually updates the formulae.

Comment: I created a small workbook mock-up. Instead of using range1, I used "WS_Range" and set it up as follows:    " Dim WS_Range As Range"      "With Sheet2"       "Set WS_Range = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(2, 11))"   "End With"     I then used    "Formula1:=WS_Range.Address(External:=True)" In the target cell I do not get Data Validation, the cell simply contains  "'WS_Range.Address(External:=True)" What have I missed, please?

Comment: @Gary add `"="&` at the beginning, formula should start with `"="`. `Formula1:="=" & WS_Range.Address(External:=True)`

Comment: @A.S.H - perfect, thank you. I'd literally spent days on this one. Much appreciated